# How to create a table out of a complex query and have it by constantly live/ updating?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, jobs

I am working for an apparel company working on their order data. 
The order data is split up into 3 databases. The ERP data that contains it's order information like price, quantity, and so on. 
The shipping data that contains all shipping information for that order. 
And a Shopify database that contains all information from Shopify using the API.

Fors the past few months, I've been created a comprehensive dashboard against all the data in these three tables.
I've been writing stored procedures against this data but the problem is that it takes a very long time to run since I have to join multiple tables across multiple databases.

I want to create a job that runs once or twice a day, reads all the new orders that came in since the last time it ran, and adds all this data to one table on one database. 
Then all my queries will use this one table making everything run a lot faster.

I would also want the job to not only add new orders, but also update old orders. Lets say my table has the field "Status". When the order is first created the Status would be "Ordered", but then 2 days later it could become "Shipped". 
And other fields, like the Shipment_Number field for example, would be null until that information is updated.

Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

Here is my large query that collects all the data that I need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
--TOP 10

O.Company_Code
,O.Division_Code

,O.Date_Entered

,O.Customer_Number

,O.Control_Number
,O.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number

,P.PickTicket_Number
,CASE 
    WHEN sh.packslip IS NULL 
        THEN ph.packslip
        ELSE sh.packslip 
END Packslip
,PST.Stage_Code Pickticket_Stage_Code

,I.Invoice_Number
,IST.Stage_Code Inovice_Stage_Code

,CASE  
    WHEN sh.packslip IS NULL
        THEN z.status 
        ELSE 'SHIPPED & UPLOADED' 
END Accellos_Status

,O.Order_Type_Code

--,O.Order_Status
,CASE 
    WHEN o.Order_Status = 30 THEN 'CANCELED' 
    WHEN o.Order_Status = 45 THEN 'SHIPPED' 
    WHEN o.Order_Status = 10 THEN 'NORMAL' 
    WHEN o.Order_Status = 20 THEN 'NORMAL' 
END Order_Status

,OD.Odet_Line_Number

--,OD.Line_Status
,CASE 
    WHEN od.Line_Status = 90 THEN 'ALLOCATED'
    WHEN od.Line_Status = 80 THEN 'CANCELED' 
    WHEN od.Line_Status = 70 THEN 'SHIPPED' 
    WHEN od.Line_Status = 50 THEN 'NORMAL' 
END Line_Status

,S.Master_Item 

,OD.Item_Number
,S.Description

,OD.Color_Code
,C.Color_Description

,OD.Quantity_Ordered
,OD.Quantity_Allocated
,OD.Quantity_Invoiced

,RT.Retail Unit_Retail
,(RT.Retail-OD.Price) Unit_MarkDown

,OD.Price Sell_Price
,OD.Discount_Value

,(OD.Price - OD.Discount_Value) Sale_Price

,((OD.Price - OD.Discount_Value)* (Royalty_Percentage/100)) Royalty_Cost


,CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(s.Actual_Cost, 0) = 0
        THEN ISNULL(s.Standard_Cost, 0)
        ELSE s.Actual_Cost  
END Item_Cost

,SR.Royalty_Code
,RC.Royalty_Percentage

,OD.Freight_Charges

--,CASE 
--  WHEN sh.packslip is null 
--      THEN ph.COST_SHIP 
--      ELSE sh.COST_SHIP 
--END Freight_Cost

,SM.Cost_Ship Master_Freight_Cost

,OD.Tax_Value

,CASE WHEN (OD.Quantity_Ordered <> OD.Quantity_Invoiced and OD.Quantity_Allocated=0) THEN OD.Quantity_Ordered - OD.Quantity_Invoiced ELSE 0 END ShortShippedAmount

,RD.Return_Number
,RD.Quantity_Returned

--,OW.Email
,CASE 
    WHEN AE.Email IS NULL -- Does it matter which one I do for then and for else? One is in the same database
        THEN OW.Email 
        ELSE AE.Email 
END Email

,CASE  --Is there a better way to do this? When one table has the information and the other does't
    WHEN sh.packslip IS NULL 
        THEN ph.ship_name 
        ELSE sh.SHIP_NAME 
END Customer_Name

,CASE 
    WHEN sh.packslip IS NULL 
        THEN ph.SHIP_ADD1 + ' ' + ph.SHIP_ADD2 
        ELSE sh.SHIP_ADD1 + ' ' + sh.SHIP_ADD2 
END Customer_Addr 

,CASE 
    WHEN sh.packslip IS NULL 
        THEN ph.SHIP_CITY 
        ELSE sh.SHIP_CITY 
END Customer_City

,CASE 
    WHEN sh.packslip is null 
        THEN ph.SHIP_PROV 
        ELSE sh.SHIP_PROV 
END Customer_State

,CASE 
    WHEN sh.packslip is null 
        THEN ph.SHIP_ZIP 
        ELSE sh.SHIP_ZIP 
END Customer_Zip 

,o.Ship_Via_Code

,CASE 
    WHEN sh.packslip is null 
        THEN ph.SHIP_VIA 
        ELSE sh.SHIP_VIA
END Ship_Via

,CASE 
    WHEN sh.packslip is null 
        THEN ph.SERVICE 
        ELSE sh.SERVICE 
END SERVICE

,CASE 
    WHEN sh.packslip is null 
        THEN ph.SHIP_NUM 
        ELSE sh.SHIP_NUM 
END Ship_Num

,OW.Gateway
,OW.Tags
,OW.FinancialState
,OW.FulfillmentState

,OW.OrderCreated Shopify_Ordered
,OW.DateCreated Pro4Soft_Created
,OW.DownloadTime Pro4Soft_Downloaded
,OW.ConfirmedDownloadTime Pro4Soft_Confirmed
,FW.DateCreated Pro4Soft_Fulfilled
,OW.OrderUpdated Pro4Soft_Updated
,OW.OrderClosed Pro4Soft_Closed
,OW.OrderCancelled Pro4Soft_Cancelled
,OW.LastSynced Pro4Soft_Last_Synced

,OTSS.AMT_Created
,OTSS.AMT_Invoiced
,OTSS.AMT_Cancelled

,PTSS.Pickticket_Created
,PTSS.Pickticket_Allocated

,RLTSS.Accellos_Download
,RLTSS.Accellos_Allocated
,RLTSS.Accellos_Waved
,RLTSS.Accellos_Label
,RLTSS.Accellos_Last_Pick
,RLTSS.Accellos_Rating
,RLTSS.Accellos_Shipped
,RLTSS.Accellos_Upload

,CASE 
    WHEN sh.packslip IS NULL
        THEN ph.Date_modfy 
        ELSE sh.Date_modfy 
END Accellos_Timestamp

,SM.Tracktrace

--,*

--AMT Tables

FROM        [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Orders O WITH (NOLOCK) 

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Order_Detail OD WITH (NOLOCK)             
                                    on O.Company_Code = OD.Company_Code
                                    and O.Division_Code = OD.Division_Code
                                    and O.Control_Number = OD.Control_Number

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].PickTickets P WITH (NOLOCK)       
                                    on O.Company_Code = P.Company_Code 
                                    and O.Division_Code = P.Division_Code
                                    and O.Control_Number = P.Control_Number

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].PickTickets_Stage PST WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                    ON o.Company_Code=pst.Company_Code 
                                    AND o.Division_Code=pst.Division_Code 
                                    AND p.PickTicket_Number=pst.PickTicket_Number

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices I WITH (NOLOCK)              
                                    on O.Company_Code = I.Company_Code 
                                    and O.Division_Code = I.Division_Code
                                    and O.Control_Number = I.Control_Number

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices_Detail ID WITH (NOLOCK)      
                                    on O.Company_Code = ID.Company_Code 
                                    and O.Division_Code = ID.Division_Code
                                    and O.Control_Number = ID.Control_Number

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices_Stage IST WITH (NOLOCK)      
                                    ON o.Company_Code = ist.Company_Code  
                                    AND o.Division_Code = ist.Division_Code 
                                    AND i.Invoice_Number = ist.Invoice_Number

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Style S WITH (NOLOCK)                     
                                    on O.Company_Code = S.Company_Code
                                    and O.Division_Code = S.Division_Code
                                    and OD.Item_Number = S.Item_Number
                                    and OD.Color_Code = S.Color_Code

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Color C WITH (NOLOCK)                     
                                    on S.Color_Code = C.Color_Code

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Returns_Header RH WITH (NOLOCK)   
                                    on O.Company_Code = RH.Company_Code
                                    and O.Division_Code = RH.Division_Code
                                    and I.Invoice_Number = RH.Invoice_Number
                                    and O.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number = RH.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Returns_Detail RD WITH (NOLOCK)   
                                    on O.Company_Code = RD.Company_Code
                                    and O.Division_Code = RD.Division_Code
                                    and O.Control_Number = RD.Control_Number
                                    and RH.Return_Number = RD.Return_Number
                                    and OD.Item_Number = RD.Item_Number
                                    and OD.Color_Code = RD.Color_Code
                                    and OD.Odet_Line_Number = RD.Odet_Line_Number

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Style_Royalty SR WITH (NOLOCK)        
                                    on S.Company_Code = SR.Company_Code
                                    and S.Division_Code = SR.Division_Code
                                    and S.Item_Number = SR.Item_Number
                                    and S.Color_Code = SR.Color_Code

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Royalty_By_Customer RC WITH (NOLOCK)  
                                    on S.Company_Code = RC.Company_Code
                                    and S.Division_Code = RC.Division_Code
                                    and SR.Royalty_Code = RC.Royalty_Code

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Z_N_FullRetailTable RT WITH (NOLOCK)
                                    on OD.Item_Number = RT.SKU
                                    and OD.Color_Code = RT.Color

LEFT JOIN   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].ArchivedEmails AE WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                    ON O.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number = AE.OrderNumber
--WMS Tables

LEFT JOIN   [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].pickhead ph WITH (NOLOCK) --When the order is not shipped and invoiced yet it is in this table.
                                    ON p.PickTicket_Number = ph.packslip

LEFT JOIN   [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].SHIPHIST sh WITH (NOLOCK) --After order is Shipped it gets deleted from Pickhead and moves to this table.
                                    ON o.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number = sh.cust_po

LEFT JOIN   [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].SHIPMSTR2 SM WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                    ON o.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number = sm.Cust_Order
                                    and sh.packslip=sm.packslip

LEFT JOIN   [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].Z_Status z WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                    ON ph.PROCSTEP = z.procstep

--Shopify Tables

LEFT JOIN   [SHOPIFY].[shopify_moret].[dbo].[OrderWrappers] OW WITH (NOLOCK)
                                    ON O.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number = OW.OrderName

LEFT JOIN   [SHOPIFY].[shopify_moret].[dbo].[FulfillmentWrappers] FW WITH (NOLOCK)
                                    ON OW.Id =FW.OrderWrapperId

--Timestampt Tables (Mix of AMT and WMS)

LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
            Company_Code
            ,Division_Code
            ,Control_Number
            ,max( case when Action like 'New%' then Date end) as AMT_Created
            ,max( case when Action like '%Invoice%' then Date end) as AMT_Invoiced
            ,max( case when Action like '%Cancel%' then Date end) as AMT_Cancelled

            FROM(
                SELECT DISTINCT
                Company_Code
                ,Division_Code
                ,Control_Number
                ,Date
                ,Action 
                from [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Order_Audit_Trail WITH (NOLOCK)
            )OTS
            group by Company_Code, Division_Code, Control_Number
        )OTSS 
            on O.Control_Number = OTSS.Control_Number 
            and O.Company_Code = OTSS.Company_Code 
            and O.Division_Code = OTSS.Division_Code

LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
            Company_Code
            ,Division_Code
            ,PickTicket_Number
            ,max( case when Action like 'Created%' then Date end) as   Pickticket_Created
            ,max( case when Action like 'Inserted%' then Date end) as  Pickticket_Allocated
            ,max( case when Action like 'Updated%' then Date end) as  Pickticket_Updated
            --,max( case when Action like '%Cancel%' then Date end) as Pickticket_Cancelled

            FROM(
                SELECT DISTINCT
                Company_Code
                ,Division_Code
                ,PickTicket_Number
                ,Date
                ,Action 
                from [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].PickTickets_Audit_Trail WITH (NOLOCK)
            )PTS
            group by Company_Code, Division_Code, PickTicket_Number
        )PTSS 
            on O.Company_Code = PTSS.Company_Code 
            and O.Division_Code = PTSS.Division_Code 
            and PTSS.PickTicket_Number = COALESCE( sh.packslip, P.PickTicket_Number) 

LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
            Packslip
            ,max( case when Action like 'DNLOAD' then Date_Time end) as     Accellos_Download
            ,max( case when Action like 'ALLOC' then Date_Time end) as      Accellos_Allocated
            ,max( case when Action like 'WAVEORDR' then Date_Time end) as   Accellos_Waved
            ,max( case when Action like 'NEWLABEL' then Date_Time end) as   Accellos_Label
            ,max( case when Action like 'EOL_LSTP' then Date_Time end) as   Accellos_Last_Pick
            ,max( case when Action like 'RATED' then Date_Time end) as      Accellos_Rating
            ,max( case when Action like 'SHIPPED' then Date_Time end) as    Accellos_Shipped
            ,max( case when Action like 'UPLOAD' then Date_Time end) as     Accellos_Upload

            FROM(
                SELECT DISTINCT
                Packslip
                ,Date_Time
                ,Action 
                from [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1Warehouse].[dbo].[RF_LOG2] RL WITH (NOLOCK)
            )RLTS
            group by Packslip
        )RLTSS 
            on  RLTSS.PACKSLIP = Coalesce(sh.PACKSLIP, TRY_CAST(P.pickticket_number as nvarchar))

WHERE                                                        
    --(O.Company_Code = '09' OR '09' IS NULL) AND 
    --(O.Division_Code = '001' OR '001' IS NULL) AND
    O.Customer_Number = 'ecom2x' AND 
    ISNUMERIC(O.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number) <> 0
    AND O.Order_Type_Code <> 'B'
    AND O.Date_Entered BETWEEN '8/1/2019' AND DATEADD(dayofyear, 1, GETDATE())

ORDER BY O.Date_Entered DESC
```

If I run this query just like that it takes over four hours for orders for the past week and who knows how many hours for all orders since the beginning of time. (although it seems like adding lines does not exponentially increase the time).

Inserting this data into a table is not too difficult I think. I can just add an insert statement before the query and let it run overnight.

The difficult part would be keeping it "live"

I think the best way to do it is to do one large insert statement once. This will get the bulk of the data into the table.

Then I would create a job that runs this query but only for the past 40 days (because after 40 days, an orders information is pretty much not going to change).

Here is a sample result:

```
Company_Code    Division_Code   Date_Entered    Customer_Number Control_Number  Customer_Purchase_Order_Number  PickTicket_Number   Packslip    Pickticket_Stage_Code   Invoice_Number  Inovice_Stage_Code  Accellos_Status Order_Type_Code Order_Status    Odet_Line_Number    Line_Status Master_Item Item_Number Description Color_Code  Color_Description   Quantity_Ordered    Quantity_Allocated  Quantity_Invoiced   Unit_Retail Unit_MarkDown   Sell_Price  Discount_Value  Sale_Price  Royalty_Cost    Item_Cost   Royalty_Code    Royalty_Percentage  Freight_Charges Master_Freight_Cost Tax_Value   ShortShippedAmount  Return_Number   Quantity_Returned   Email   Customer_Name   Customer_Addr   Customer_City   Customer_State  Customer_Zip    Ship_Via_Code   Ship_Via    SERVICE Ship_Num    Gateway Tags    FinancialState  FulfillmentState    Shopify_Ordered Pro4Soft_Created    Pro4Soft_Downloaded Pro4Soft_Confirmed  Pro4Soft_Fulfilled  Pro4Soft_Updated    Pro4Soft_Closed Pro4Soft_Cancelled  Pro4Soft_Last_Synced    AMT_Created AMT_Invoiced    AMT_Cancelled   Pickticket_Created  Pickticket_Allocated    Accellos_Download   Accellos_Allocated  Accellos_Waved  Accellos_Label  Accellos_Last_Pick  Accellos_Rating Accellos_Shipped    Accellos_Upload Accellos_Timestamp  Tracktrace
1   7   14:00.4 ECOM2X      511322  1721057 NULL    11422781    NULL    10704058    PRINTREADY  SHIPPED & UPLOADED  N   SHIPPED 1   SHIPPED 1950    17DN19501XLEC   PLUS SIZE BERMUDA SHORT 115 RICH BLACK                                          2   0   2   28  0   28  0   28  1.96    6.49    DANSKIN     7   0   7.71    0   0   NULL    NULL    wwright5333@yahoo.com   Wendy WRIGHT    5596 NORTH RD   FRIENDSVILLE    PA  18818   SGRD    USPS    Priority Mail   SHP1580902  shopify_payments    Riskified::approved, Riskified::submitted   paid    fulfilled   2019-08-06 12:12:47.0000000 +00:00  2019-08-06 12:13:30.2019290 +00:00  2019-08-06 12:13:41.9336199 +00:00  2019-08-06 12:14:20.5300000 +00:00  2019-08-06 22:31:37.3958947 +00:00  2019-08-06 23:45:11.0000000 +00:00  2019-08-06 22:31:05.0000000 +00:00  NULL    2019-08-06 23:45:30.1978836 +00:00  14:00.5 30:09.6 NULL    14:01.0 NULL    20190806 08:17:23.67    20190806 08:19:43.82    20190806 08:19:56.43    20190806 08:19:57.18    20190806 11:18:57.31    20190806 12:50:32.00    20190806 15:57:50.87    20190806 15:58:01.76    57:50.8 9.40552E+21
```

So that is what I need help with.

How do I create a procedure/job that compares the last 30-40 days of orders from the table, and see what is new in the lines from the query.
And then I can run this job once or twice a day to update all the timestamp and shipping information.

Maybe it would be better to create two version of this job? One that runs once a day only for the past week to update all timestamp information and one that runs once a week for the past 30-60 days to update all the return information. 
Or is this too complicated?

The job would need to check to see if there were any changes per line, and if there were update it. And if there wasn't, do nothing. Is there anyway to optimize it towards that? Like as soon as it sees the line has no changes, it skips it.

(Also, if anyone has any general tips for the query, I would greatly appreciate that. I tried to make it as readable as possible.)

Also, is it better to do all the math like this

```
    ,((OD.Price - OD.Discount_Value)* (Royalty_Percentage/100)) Royalty_Cost
```

There in the stored procedure so the result is already in my table, or is it better to do my calculation on the queries I will make against this new table? Or does it not matter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad, but you might want to look into materialized views.  I would also discourage a company from running dashboard queries on operational systems.  The databases should be replicated for decision support purposes.

Comment: Also doing cross server joins means it's pulling ALL the data over in order to determine if the join conditions are met. Agree with @GordonLinoff, you should have a replicated copy of your data refreshed at certain times of the day.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been writing stored procedures against this data but the problem is that it takes a very long time to run since I have to join multiple tables across multiple databases.

The "multiple databases" problem isn't a problem.  SQL Server databases are administrative & security boundaries, but selecting/joining across databases presents no difficulty.  All database statistics are available to query optimizer.

> I want to create a job that ... adds all this data to one table on one database

Be careful what you wish for.  As you've already foreseen, maintaining that table will be work, and it will never be up to date.  Even as it's being updated, information in the base tables may change.

The *materialized views* suggestion is a good one, but there are aspects of this query that really make it tough on the query optimizer, starting with the number of tables.

The simplest improvement is to use the **coalesce** instead of the `IF X IS NULL` construct.  That might help some.

I assume you have indexes appropriate to each join, and that you've confirmed they're being used.  If the indexes aren't clustered indexes, you may find covering indexes are more helpful.  (A covering index has many of the same benefits as a materialized view.)

The way you use the "Timestamp Tables" is especially problematic.  The trivial mistake is SELECT DISTINCT in a subquery whose results are aggregated (with GROUP BY).  The distinct is unnecessary; if you're lucky, it's eliminated anyway during optimization.

More important is the price you're paying for constructs like

```
,max( case when Action like 'New%' then Date end) as AMT_Created
```

because the system has to pattern-match every row, more than once.  If anything needs to be written to intermediate tables, it's those queries.

Left joins also impose a cost.  Are they really necessary?  Perhaps you could check for cross-database consistency periodically (maybe every 15 minutes or so) and use inner joins in your queries.

Two more points:

1. Make sure the server has enough RAM.  More is better, especially for joins.
2. Push hard to *fully* understand the query optimizer's report, and make sure every one of your stored procedures is accessing the tables in an optimal way.  Very generally speaking, the solution to SQL Server performance is indexes first, temporary tables second, and everything else last.

Everyone is tempted sooner or later to solve performance problems with one big "flat" table.  It's a lot of work, and rarely turns out well.  Better to isolate the weird troublemakers and keep the duplicated data in your database to a minimum.